# Bubble visualization with a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am a completely new to D3.

I'd like to visualize easy results of tests in bubbles, e.g. Name: mathematics, completed-tests: 340, name: Latin, completed tests: 550.

When I look at the example on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269, I can see that only a CSV file is loaded.

According to the documentation it is also possible to load a JSON file, but I didn't find the correct "semantic" for the JSON file.

What should the JSON file look like and how should it be called in the JavaScript section of the `index.html`?

Note: I want to use version 4.0. Does it matter?

Comment: D3 is **not** a framework. I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question here is not about the correct *structure* of the JSON file, since there is no *correct structure*: it depends on the code.

Your question here is, given that **specific code** you linked, how can you change the CSV for a JSON.

To answer that, you have to understand how `d3.csv` creates an array of objects. In the Bostock's code you linked, each object in that array has an `id` and a `value` key/value pair.

Therefore, your JSON need to have a structure like this:

```
[{
    "id": "flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster",
    "value": 1938
}, {
    "id": "flare.analytics.cluster.CommunityStructure",
    "value": 3812
}, {
    "id": "flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster",
    "value": 2714
}, {
    "id": "flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge",
    "value": 1743
}]
```

Since you are creating your own JSON you don't need to mind the row function, which removes the objects without `value` and coerces their values to a number.

Here is the updated bl.ocks using a JSON file (with just some objects): https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/4ca57ea4393a37bc92091325eba295dd

Have in mind that, if you use the data structure you described in your question...

```
[{"Name": "mathematics", "completed-tests": 340}, etc...]
```

... you will have to make several changes in Bostock's code, both in `d3.hierarchy` and in the `node` selection.

Comment: Thanks for you help :-) When I want to have the bubbles in different colors, I only have to edit the id, correct? I edited them to "flare.AgglomerativeCluster.AgglomerativeCluster", "flare.CommunityStructure.CommunityStructure". Is it the right way or should is there a better way?

Comment: It depends on how do you want to color them. In Bostock's code, it is an ordinal scale for the package name.